# Xamarin Forms - XAML Hot Reload encountered a problem and failed to start

Tags: ios, macos, debugging, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have created a brand new Xamarin forms application. When I want to start the iOS app, it shows a blue screen (I think the default launching screen) and gives the output beneath.

Also, when I click on the app again in the emulator after I had started it, it works, but for my other project it doesn't, it puts the app back to the background.

> Resolved pending breakpoint for 'UIKit.UIApplication.Main(System.String[], System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr)' to /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.16.0.13/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:85 [0x00000].
>   [HotReload] (2020-04-14 18:53:24.6): INFO: XAML Hot Reload Initializing...
>   [HotReload] (2020-04-14 18:53:25.0): WARN: (App7.iOS) Unknown Breakpoint Hit: UIKit.UIApplication.Main(string[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate)
>   [HotReload] (2020-04-14 18:55:24.7): ERROR: Caught exception in AgentStatusChangedHandler at 201: Xamarin.HotReload.DebuggerTimeoutException: Failed to Inject Assembly
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
>   [HotReload] (2020-04-14 18:55:24.7): INFO: XAML Hot Reload encountered a problem and failed to start. Use Help -> Report a Problem if the issues persists.
>   [HotReload] (2020-04-14 18:55:24.7): INFO: Stopping All Hot Reload sessions due to Failed ...
>   [HotReload] (2020-04-14 18:55:24.7): INFO: (App7.iOS) Stopped Hot Reload session due to Failed ...
>   [HotReload] (2020-04-14 18:55:24.7): INFO: Stopped Hot Reload session.

Answer (score 0):

> XAML Hot Reload encountered a problem and failed to start. Use Help ->
>   Report a Problem if the issues persists.

It looks like the initialization of hot reload failed.

Please follow the steps where the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload#troubleshooting) listed to solve this problem:

- If XAML Hot Reload fails to initialize:

  1. Update your Xamarin.Forms version.
  2. Ensure you are on the latest version of the IDE.
  3. Set your Android or iOS Linker settings to Don't Link in the project's build settings.
- If nothing happens upon saving your XAML file, ensure that XAML Hot
  Reload is enabled in the IDE.
- If you're debugging on a physical iPhone and your app becomes
  unresponsive, check that the interpreter is enabled. To turn it on,
  check Enable the Mono interpreter (Visual Studio 16.4/8.4 and up) or
  add --interpreter to the Additional mtouch arguments field (Visual
  Studio 16.3/8.3 and prior) in your iOS Build settings.

Here are some threads may also help: [Troubleshooting XAML Hot Reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-hot-reload-troubleshooting?view=vs-2019) and [Hot Reload not working on iOS Simulator](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/670112/hot-reload-not-working-on-ios-simulator.html)

Comment: 1. I have the latest xamarin.forms version. 2. IDE is also on the latest version. 3. Linker Settings are already on don't link. 4. Hot reload is also enabled.

Comment: Then you should report a Problem if the issues persists!

Answer (score 0):

--> **SOLUTION** Make sure that the MAC and your PC are in the same network! The problem on my side was caused by a VPN connection that is causing visual studio to connect on a different route to the MAC and therefore something is breaking the connection for HOT Reload! As soon as i connected my laptop with the wifi at my company it was working. We are looking to find a way to confige the VPN / MAC access differently.

Original Answer:

I had exactly the same problem as you. I felt I was trying all kinds of solutions and nothing helped. The problem occured after I updated Visual Studio 2019 (PC & MAC) and xCode. Then after 8 hours of debugging and analyzing hundreds of log files I found a solution.

I connected to a computer at work that was just set up and had a new "unused" installation of VS2019. I retrieved the TFS project and ran iOS. It has been compiled and Hot Reload started directly!

I have no explanation myself and it took me hours but it seems that only a fresh install can fix the problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask you when this problem occured? (what date?)

Comment: I encountered that problem today. I could not upgrade my Mac to Catalina on firday so it took some time to reset it. I had to Upgrade the MAC OS to upgrade xCode to be used with the newest version of Visual Studio (PC). So i assume that the problem occured since Visual Studio 15.1.4. Before that everything worked just fine. (But i think i jumped a bunch of versions)

Comment: But even more weird is the fact that it just works on the other workstation for no paticular reason. I really dont get it. There is no difference in the code (TFS) and all software Versions are the same VS and the connected MAC. it just works. But i need a way to amke it work on my notebook anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I used VS 2019 Professional , and had this same problem with Android and then I switched from Professional to Enterprise Version of VS 2019.
And I reinstalled each and every tools again. Then now it's working fine without any errors.